# How to bypass port blocking for p2p network?

Tags: networking, port, isp, p2p

I noticed that my school is now blocking all the ports to prevent p2p network such as torrent downloading. Of course it is against school's policy to bypass it. However I am curious if there is method to bypass port blocking to access p2p network?

Also I am running a OS X 10.9.2.

Comment: Depends highly on what kind of firewall(s) are used and where.  Besides, if they're going to the effort of blocking ports, there's probably a good reason why.

Comment: Of course they do. So?

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/533/handling-questions-clearly-trying-to-break-some-kind-of-policy-tos-etc?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As cybernard said, a VPN will get round this (I differ with him here in as much as its almost impossible to block a VPN - OpenVPN can, among many other configurations, can use port 80 tcp (ie http) and port 443 (https).

I'm pretty sure this is going to fall on deaf ears (Ah to be young !!!), but you should seriously consider not trying to bypass the Firewall - I don't know where you are in the world, but the consequences of getting caught can far outweigh the benefits - and make no mistake, if you use this heavily and the system administrators are not asleep at the wheel you will get caught eventually.

Comment: Which VPN do you use?

Comment: OpenVPN is among the best.  Also note that in my response I said consider not trying to bypass the VPN.  I meant not trying to bypass the Firewall.

Answer (score 2):

If they don't block them a vpn to someone else or a proxy server.  However,p2p, is high volume traffic and they will probably detect it and you will get in trouble.

Suggestions:

http://proxpn.com/

Answer (score 1):

VPN is your best shot, but got it for sure, they're monitoring bandwidth connections, so get for sure that if you 'hoard' all the speed, you'll get busted in no time, so if you want to do it, try some software that allow you to 'cap' your speed, so they can't suspect of you, and be smart, don't try to download a huge file in a whole batch, it will be very notorious in the network log, and eventually they will catch you

Comment: Which VPN application do you suggest? Are they expensive?

Comment: well, i'm not giving you that info, because *certain rules* but you could use Google to find that stuff, is not that hard, there are free and per-paid VPN's i would recommend paid ones, those are more 'safe' than free ones and are more 'faster'

Comment: Alternatively, purchase a LEB (low end box, ie cheap virtual machine), and run one yourself.  It may provide lower latency depending on where you are in the world.

Comment: Not sure which rules you are talking about, but you can recommend whatever you like as long as you explain why.